# Is there way to see a all @RequestMapping URLs In IntelliJ like STS RequestMapping view?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know that STS has @RequestMapping view function(?). Nowadays, I use IntelliJ IDEA, and I wonder if IntelliJ also has a function / plugin to see the URLs of @RequestMapping like this.